# Use formatted cell if the value is in certain bounds

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am having a grading scale and would like to map my grades to the grading scale.

[image]

I tried to use just `VLOOKUP()`, however, the formatting is not taken and also some bounds are breached.

Any recommendation, how to use the formatting in my resultCell?

Comment: Which one is `<=`? As in, if I get a 2, is that `Perfect`, or `Perfect-`?  I also have to ask, why `low-` is ranked higher than `low`?

Comment: You are right! So it is from 0 to <= 2 and from > 2 to <= 4 etc. from > 4 to <= 6 etc. The actual mapping to the Grades is the hardest part for me.

Comment: If there are no decimals, and it's just whole numbers, use this for that section: `(1-2,3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-11)`

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I have decimal numbers. The hardest part is the actual mapping for me to f.ex.: `3,4`

Comment: You might need to double check the values for >2 from my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use conditional formatting.

To get the result name to print, use this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH($E2,$B$2:$B$6,1))
```

**For the Number:**
Reproduce these steps:

- Change your table so the values aren't equal to each other, as in, the `Perfect(Max)` shouldn't be the same as the `perfect-(Min)`.
- Take the result cell, and go to Conditional Formatting.
- Highlight Cell Rules > Between
- Select the cells that contain the min and max for that particular color.
- Select "with" Custom Format
- Select the color you want for that result
- Repeat for each color you want used.

[image: Screen1]
[image: Screen2]

For the "Perfect" Result:
Repeat the same as above, except use `Highlight Cell Rules` > `Equal To` Then select the appropriate values for each color, ie, "Perfect" for Dark Green, etc.  Use the actual cell address.

[image: Image3]

[image: One]
[image: TWo]
[image: Three]
[image: Four]
[image: Five]
[image: Six]
[image: Seven]

Comment: It should. I just tested it on my sheet, and it does.  Did you see the values in my sheet?  `0-1.99`?  As long as the max from one isn't overlapping the other, you have a few choices as to how to do that.  You could say `perfect: 0 <= x < 2` with `perfect-: 2<= x < 4`.... or you could say `perfect: 0 <= x <= 1.99` with `perfect-: 2<= x <= 3.99`  The latter being the equivalent of `Between`.

Comment: I used the conditional formatting, and selected the actual cell with the min and max, you can see the addresses in the pictures, with the values.

Comment: No, it returns `Perfect-`  I revised the answer to show the screenshots of that specific example.

Comment: @pnuts, I understand now.  I may have misunderstood the scope of the grades, but there was ambiguity from the start on that.  I think everyone is on the same page now.  I just NOW understood what you meant.  :D

Answer (score 0):

You will want to leave the fourth parameter of the `=VLOOKUP()` formula as `TRUE` for an approximate match. This allows you to get "map/lookup" values in-between the ranges of numbers.

This should do the trick, just play with the cutoffs to get the behavior you desire:

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Various adjustments that would normally be considered quite minor might make this question a lot easier to answer, but taking the details as they are (with `Start` assumed to be in C2, `3,4` assumed to be three and four tenths and the required output as shown in G3 and G4), in G3 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(F3=0;"perfect";IFERROR(INDEX(B:B;MATCH(F3;C:C;0)-1);INDEX(B:B;MATCH(F3;C:C))))
```

Select ColumnG, HOME > Conditional Formatting – New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**:

> Specific Text
>
> containing

```
perfect
```

<kbd>Format…</kbd>, dark green fill, OK.

Repeat rules as below:

[image: SO27924730 example]

Where the order is important because “contains low” will find both `low` and `low-` so orange should be applied after red.

What might have made things easier is:

To have columns B and C switched over (ColumnD is not required) to allow use of VLOOKUP instead of INDEX/MATCH.

To change the break points (so that the `START` values are not the end of the previous range and part of that and hence the need to attempt an exact match before resorting to an inexact one).

To classify without relying on the `-` for differentiation (to avoid the ordering issue mentioned above).

To place `perfect` in B2, to avoid the equality issues mentioned in a comment (and I think not addressed in the accepted answer).